# Completely hide WPF window on startup?

Tags: .net, wpf, window

I want that my window is completely hidden on the startup. No window, no entry in the taskbar. The user doesn't see, the application is started.

How can I realize that?

Thank you!

Comment: Will he be able to open the window later?

Comment: Out of interest, what problem does this actually solve? You may need to think about using os mutexes to prevent multiple instances of your app starting. A user might think that they mis-clicked if nothing opens...

Comment: @LukeN: One valid use case is using your GUI application as a command-line program (in which case you want it to execute the command in the background without popping up, then exit). Sometimes it's not viable to make two versions of an application just to have rarely used command-line support.

Comment: @LukeN Silent printing implementation would be another use case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

An alternative to H.B.'s method is just to set the `Visibility` to hidden and set `ShowInTaskbar` to false. This still creates the window and lets it do its thing.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you sure of your statement ? I'm currently trying to use your trick and it seems that the `Load` event of `MainWindow` is never raised if Visibility is `Hidden`.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin Load event is fired when the window is first seen, since it is never seen it is never fired. Try using the initialized event instead if you need to execute some stuff after the window is constructed.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Was easier to use @H.B. 's answer. IE don't create and show a window if I don't want one.

Comment: In my case i could not switch the visibility from `Hidden` to `Visible`, so i use `ShowInTaskbar="False"` + `WindowState="Minimized"`. then i could change them in code easily

Answer (score 45):

Don't show the window. By default there is a [`StartupUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) defined in the `App.xaml`, remove it and override the `OnStartup` method in the code-behind to create a window, just [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) and [`Hide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide.aspx) it as you wish.

Answer (score 21):

Simply don't create a window, just delete the `StartupUri` from App.xaml.

It might be helpful to set the Application to `ShutDownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` this will prevent that your application shuts down if your last window was closed.

Comment: I don't think that you are actually required to set ShutDownMode to OnExplicitShutdown. I think this is only needed if he doesn't want the app to shutdown when he finally does show a window, and then closes it

Comment: Depending on the application he wants to create it might be useful, otherwise the app will close as soon as the last window is closed as you said. This will give him explicit control over the Application life cycle. But I'll edit my answer a bit to reflect that it is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement:
Start a process to show a window, and embed it into a wpf control. The window must be loaded normally, trigger initialized/loaded events, then run as child window in control.

My solution:
Set the window width and height to 1, after loaded, resize it to normal size. The window will be shown in short time, almost 1 second. User will not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

If a window should be created but not displayed, just don't show it. Set '-s' command line argument to run in silent mode.

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the command line arguments
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        var silentMode = args.Count() > 1 && args[1].ToLower().Equals("-s");

        // If silent mode is enabled, the window is not displayed
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        if (!silentMode) mainWindow.Show();
    }
```