# C# WPF Message Only Window

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I create a WPF Window that is hidden from the world but can still receive WndProc messages? If I set the visibility to Hidden or Collapsed no messages are received by WndProc!

Comment: What messages are you expecting?

Comment: `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`. I'm porting some WinForms code to WPF and the old WinForms project had a hidden window that took care of registering for device notifications

Comment: Have you considered hosting the Winforms Window in your WPF app?

Comment: The helpful answer is given http://stackoverflow.com/a/2575839/3780573.